# Press button in Form1 and check radio button in Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

I have two Forms 1 & 2. In `Form2` I have a `Button` and in `Form1` I have a `RadioButton`. When I press the `Button` in `Form2` , I want that `RadioButton` will get checked in `Form1`. How to do that? I'm using c# in winform.

Comment: are you opening form1 from form2 or form2 from form1? probably a delegate will do the job for you, make a try

Comment: Would be great if you could share your attempted code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a minimal example:

```
    //FORM 1
    Form form1 = new Form();
    Button button1 = new Button();
    Button button2 = new Button();
    button2.Top = button1.Bottom;
    form1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { button1, button2 });

    //FORM 2
    Form form2 = new Form();
    RadioButton rb1 = new RadioButton();
    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
    rb2.Top = rb1.Bottom;
    form2.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] { rb1, rb2 });

    //CLICK EVENT
    button1.Click += (s, e) => { rb1.Invoke(new Action(() => { rb1.Checked = true; })); };
    button2.Click += (s, e) => { rb2.Invoke(new Action(() => { rb2.Checked = true; })); };

    //ONE THREAD FOR EACH FORM
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { form1.ShowDialog(); })).Start();
    new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => { form2.ShowDialog(); })).Start();
```

Ask if you have question about it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one way to do this. Here are 3 possible solutions
My choice would be the second solution

**First solution**: subscribe to the click event of the button on Form2

```
Form2 form = new Form2();
form.button1.Click += MyClick; //the modifier property of button1 must be public for this to work

void MyClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   radioButton1.Checked = true;
}
```

**second solution**: public method on Form1 and pass reference of Form1

in form1 have this code

```
public void SetRadioButtonChecked(bool value)
{
    radioButton1.Checked = value;
}
```

and call Form2 like this

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this); // this works only if done in Form1 !
```

in form2 have this code

```
private Form1 _caller = null;

public Form2(Form1 caller)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _caller = caller;
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _caller.SetRadioButtonChecked(true);
}
```

**third solution**: pass a handle to the form and use the radioButton directly

```
Form2 form = new Form2(this); // this works only if done in Form1 !
```

in form2 have this code

```
private Form1 _caller = null;

public Form2(Form1 caller)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _caller = Caller;
}

void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _caller.radioButton1.Checked = true;
}
```